# Reading .xlsx Using Google Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm attempting to read .xlsx files using the Google Drive API, however after I've successfully opened the file and decide to read the contents it displays garbage values. I'm able to read the metadata and have verified that the correct file has been opened. Here is what is getting called once the file is successfully read. It works with .txt files but I recieve garbage values with any .word, .xlsx files.

```
private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Error while opening the file contents");
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "File contents opened");
                    mProgressBar.setProgress(100);

                    DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            builder.append(line);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                    String contentsAsString = builder.toString();

                    mTextViewContent.setText(contentsAsString);
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

With Google Drive API, [downloading Google documents](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) is done by exporting your file to a supported MIME type.

But, if your using Google Drive Android API, in [opening the file contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files#opening_the_file_contents)

> In order to be able to read a file, you must start by opening its `DriveContents` resource in `DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY` or `DriveFile.MODE_READ_WRITE` mode, depending on whether you prefer to work with the `InputStream` or `ParcelFileDescriptor` class.

You may want to check the given documentations for a more detailed information and this [GitHub post](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/RetrieveContentsWithProgressDialogActivity.java).